# Concatenating txt files and keeping directory name

Tags: linux, directory, cat, text

I am concatenating thousands of .txt files together but I want to keep the path written above the text of each .txt file so I can refer back to the directory to review files if needed.

Example:

file1.txt has the following content:

```
id: 1234
info: 1234
id: abcd
info: abcd
```

*The path to file1.txt is pathto/dir1/sub1/file1.txt*

file2.txt has the following content:

```
id: 5678
info: 5678
```

*The path to file2.txt is pathto/dir2/sub2/file2.txt*

The .txt file after concatenating should be formatted like:

```
pathto/dir1/sub1/file1.txt

id: 1234
info: 1234
id: abcd
info: abcd

pathto/dir2/sub2/file2.txt

id: 5678
info: 5678
```

Concatenating alone does not print the path in between each concatenated .txt file which is what I am trying to accomplish.

I will also cd ~/ into `pathto/` and would need to run a command from there that will recursively scan all subdirectories looking for "file.txt" files

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the directory name on top of the contents of each file? Can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/737128/edit) the question to clarify? Maybe add example output enclosed in code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Hopefully I explained it better in the edit.

Comment: how are you choosing which files are concatenated, are you entering directories by hand, or are you going throug some loop and running cat command or something else on a path, if you are entering directories by hand you can use pwd command with output to file and then concatenate with >> to file to append to a file that has the path on top. If you are using some loop you can write the path you are entering to top of the file and then append with >> to the same file the concatenation

Comment: they all share the same name. I would concatenate by doing:
cat filename.txt > filename_merged.txt for example

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to add the complete path to each file if you have thousands of files?

Comment: I notice that you have asked several questions but have yet to accept _any_ of the answers you have received. Consider accepting the most helpful answers to each question. Doing so will mark the issue as resolved and increase your chances of getting help in the future. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I added an update to my original question. I wonder if it's possible to work off of that command?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I am just trying to wrap my head around some of the answers and created a test directory to see if the answers are helping.

Comment: Hey Valentin, this worked except it only showed the first directory. I have dir1 and dir 2. How can I get it to show from all directories/subdirectories? Also, how can i have this output to a file?

Comment: That is interesting because within terminal I am in the directory 'test'. within 'test' is 'dir1' and 'dir2', each of those have a couple subdirectories and then a file called file.txt. i made this just for testing. anyways, when i run the command it only concatenates the data from dir1 and shows nothing from dir2. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: See: https://i.imgur.com/4Cw7Cp2.png

Comment: Perfect, this worked! Last thing, how can I have the command ignore case? Some file names might be file.txt and some might be File.txt

Comment: Well you can use `-iname`  or   if it is a matter of `File` or `file`  then `'[Ff]ile?.txt'`  will work. Since `find` supports `-iname`  just use that.

Comment: Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop across the to level of directories, loop across each set of subdirectories, loop across the files. Something like this

```
for topdir in */
do
    top=${topdir%/}
    top=${top##*/}

    for subdir in "$topdir"/*/
    do
        sub=${subdir%/}
        sub=${sub##*/}

        printf -- '-%s\n--%s\n\n' "$top" "$sub"

        for file in "$subdir"/*
        do
            [ -f "$file" ] && cat <"$file"
        done
    done
done >output_file
```

I've used an explicit loop across files to ensure I'm only trying to concatenate files. You could dispense with that if you know for sure there are only files in each subdirectory.

---

In response to your amended question I can offer this significantly shorter solution. This searches from the current directory for files called `file.txt` and concatenates them with their pathnames to the `output_file`.

```
find . -type f -name 'file.txt' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do printf "%s\n\n" "${f#./}"; cat "$f"; echo; done' _ {} + >output_file
```

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate the response. Though this is a bit above my skill level. There was a comment from Valentin that worked well except it only concatenated within 1 directory and not all. The command is: find . -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '\n%P\n'  -exec cat {} \;  I would also like this to output to a file instead of writing the results within terminal.

Comment: @linuxuser24569 the code is complicated so it can generate the `-dir` and `--subdir` lines you described. If you were happy with each file's path I would have offered `find` as a one line solution

Comment: @linuxuser24569 I have amended my answer to reflect the requirements in your modified question

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like your shell can do it out of the box:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nocaseglob nullglob

for file in **/file.txt **/files.txt; do
  printf '---------------------\n' >> allfiles.txt
  printf '%s' "${file}" >> allfiles.txt
  printf '---------------------\n' >> allfiles.txt
  cat "${file}" >> allfiles.txt
done
```

Comment: Hey Marcus, here is what i worked for me yesterday

```sh
find . -type f -iname 'file.txt' -printf '\n%P\n'  -exec cat {} \; > catfile.txt
```

Comment: not reacting to you until you start accepting good answers to your previous questions.

Comment: hey marcus are you able to post my answer so i can accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By your question and comments it would seem you are entering the folder and then doing something like this:

```
cat filename* > concatenatedfile.txt
```

Basically just running cat on all files that start with `filename`.

You can use `pwd` command first, and then run `cat` to just put path to the top of the file, and then append concatenation to the file.

```
pwd > concatenatedfile.txt
cat filename* >> concatenatedfile
```

This way you will create concatenatedfile.txt that has the path of the folder you are in, and then with `>>` you just append the contents of all the files that start with filename to the same file.

`>` overwrites the content of the file

`>>` appends to the end of the file, what is at top of the file stays unchanged

Comment: im gonna look more into the pwd command. i couldnt figure it out yesterday but i did accept another answer that worked

```sh
find . -type f -iname 'file.txt' -printf '\n%P\n'  -exec cat {} \; > catfile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked in the end:

```bash
find . -type f -iname 'file.txt' -printf '\n%P\n'  -exec cat {} \; > catfile.txt
```

Finds all files titled `file.txt` regardless of case and prints the data to an output file called `catfile.txt`.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: can an admin take over this answer so I can accept it? it was posted in the comments of my original post. not able to accept that as the answer there.

Comment: You can accept your own answer after 24 hours, but it would be better if possible to accept someone else's answer that worked best for you

Comment: This doesn't answer the question you asked. (1) In the question you said you had two levels of directory but in a comment you belatedly mentioned that you had lots of levels of directory. (2) Here you're printing the file pathname between files, not the `-dir` and `--subdir` that you specified

Comment: @roaima I edited my original post. I hope it better explains the answer that I posted and will select tomorrow.